# Neovim change te and terminal command

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to change the behaviour of the :te and :terminal in neovim. I added

```
cmap VTerm te
```

to my init.vim. This is supposed to open a erminal in a vertical split, but it doesn't seem to work. I also wanted to remap the :terminal command to do the same thing. What am I doing wrong?

Also I'm using this [plugin](https://github.com/vimlab/split-term.vim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try these abbreviations:

```
cnorea <expr> te       getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() ==# 'te'       ? 'VTerm' : 'te'
cnorea <expr> terminal getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() ==# 'terminal' ? 'VTerm' : 'terminal'
```

Both of them check whether you're on a regular Ex command-line (`getcmdtype() == ':'`) and whether you've typed `te` or `terminal` at the beginning of the line (`getcmdline() ==# 'te'`, `getcdmline() ==# 'terminal'`).

If you aren't on a regular Ex command-line (search, input, debug, ...), or if you've typed `te` / `terminal` anywhere else than the beginning of the line, they won't be expanded into `VTerm`. Otherwise they will.